# jquery dialog won't open again after closing

Tags: php, jquery, html

I cannot find an answer in previous posts so I'll share my code and hopefully someone can tell me why my dialog won't open after I have closed it the first time.

script:

```
addressdialog = $( "#address-form" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  height: 550,
  width: 450,
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
    Submit: function(){
        form[0].submit();
    },
    Cancel: function() {
      addressdialog.dialog( "close" );
    }
  },
  close: function() {
    form[ 0 ].reset();
    allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
  }
});

$( "#create-address" ).click( function() {
  addressdialog.dialog( "open" );
});
```

I can't get my html div to display.... let me know if it is required but I figure the problem is with the script.

Comment: add `addressdialog.dialog( "close" );` to the Submit button also

Comment: Not enough known...provide demo that replicates problem

Comment: Are you sure you have the only element on your page (probably a button) with id `create-address`? Also you can check many of script errors in Chrome developer console, opens on F12 key press.